# Ошибка GlassFish v3 requires a JDK 1.6 and not a JRE.

Tags: windows, eclipse, glassfish, java

Вот по этой инструкции - [Eclipse 3.6 and GlassFish 3.1 integration](http://glassfishplugins.java.net/eclipse36/index.html) - установил плагин GlassFish для Eclipse. Единственное отличие от текста: вместо Eclipse 3.6 использую Eclipse 3.7, поэтому ссылка на плагин `http://download.java.net/glassfish/eclipse/indigo`. После запуска сервера выскакивает ошибка:

> `GlassFish v3 requires a JDK 1.6 and not a JRE.`

JDK установлена. Что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо прописать путь к JDK в настройках сервера.

> `Windows -> Preferences -> Runtime Environments`

Клик по серверу. `Edit`. И выбрать установленный JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Фишка в том что в Windows – Preferences – Java – Installed JRE путь установить не к JRE, а к JDK. В дальнейшем  в разделе Server - Runtime Environment  выбрать JDK.